# How to make sure the answer is limited to Positive Reals?

Tags: equation-solving

As the title described, there is code:

```
Solve[{Subscript[L, y2]/Subscript[L, y1] == 1/Sqrt[1 - v^2/c^2]},v] /. {Subscript[L, y1] -> 1/2, Subscript[L, y2] -> Sqrt[3]/2}
```

I have searched in the help doc, but the options I can find are `Reals`、`Integers` and `Complexes`. I don't know how to limit the positive domain or others by myself. = =

Answer (score 3):

You can use the domain `PositiveReals` just like below.

```
In[1]:= Solve[{Subscript[L, y2]/Subscript[L, y1] == 1/Sqrt[1 - v^2/c^2]}, v, PositiveReals] /. {Subscript[L, y1] -> 1/2, Subscript[L, y2] -> Sqrt[3]/2}

Out[1]= {{v -> ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[2/3] Sqrt[c^2], c > 0]}}
```

Comment: `PositiveReals` is new in v12. In earlier versions include constraints in `Solve`, e.g., `Solve[{Subscript[L,y2]/Subscript[L,y1]==1/Sqrt[1-v^2/c^2]/.{Subscript[L,y1]->1/2,Subscript[L,y2]->Sqrt[3]/2},v>0,Element[c,Reals]},v]` or `Solve[{Subscript[L,y2]/Subscript[L,y1]==1/Sqrt[1-v^2/c^2]/.{Subscript[L,y1]->1/2,Subscript[L,y2]->Sqrt[3]/2},v>0,c>0},v]`